# Get rows inserted and updated dynamically in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I need to get the rows inserted and updated in each table through my SSIS package.
Is there any way to do it except using the row count transformation component  before each insert or update component.

Is there any option in SSIS that provide that information without doing it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on your SSIS version, but see [Integration Services (SSIS) Logging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140246%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) in the official documentation.

Assuming a reasonably modern deployment I can show you an example of SQL 2012 Basic Logging for SSIS packages. It's very simple, as it is the default configuration, and all you need to do is drill down the provided reports by right clicking on your package and selecting the appropriate report.

First confirm your logging level in SSISDB:

[image]

Basic reporting will include a final rows written for your destination. It doesn't provide row counts throughout, if you want that level of detail either increase the logging level (will affect performance and storage!) or create your own solution.

[image]

You should be able to query all of the log tables and generate your own reports. Microsft just ships a pre-built set of reports that sit atop the basic logging.

Answer (score 0):

There is a custom Row Count transformation developed by the people in SQLIS.com that you can try. Please review http://www.sqlis.com/post/Row-Count-Plus-Transformation.aspx.

Besides that, I'm not aware of a different thing in order to count the rows inserted or updated.